# Плагин W3 Total Cache не формирует директорию wp-content/cache/tmp

Tags: wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin

Поставил плагин W3 Total Cache, выставляю настройки, сохраняю, он не сохраняет и не оптимизирует соответственно. В админке пишет такие ошибки:

```
Can't change configuration: Can't create folder /data/wpuser/web/public/wp-content/cache/tmp: mkdir(): No such file or directory
```

1. не создает директорию с файлами:

   The Page Cache add-in file advanced-cache.php is not a W3 Total Cache drop-in. It should be removed. Кнопка [Yes, remove it for me]

Стоит еще плагин WP Super Cache, но он отключен. 
П.С.: плагин удалять не нужно, т.к. в итоге нужно сравнить оптимизацию производительности этих двух плагинов на данном сайте.

Comment: Права на папки.файлы, скорее всего, неправильные. Должно быть 755 на папки и 644 на файлы. Владелец тот же, под кем выполняется php

Comment: @KAGGDesign это же полноценный ответ. Думаю, стоит ответить, чтобы ТС отметил решенным вопрос.

Comment: @SeVlad а он не отреагировал - помогло или нет. Может, еще в чем-то дело (код покорежили), но вряд ли.

Comment: @KAGG Design, не совсем в этом дело

Comment: @Александр как раз в этом -  KAGG Design полный ответ дал. И про права и про владельца (это тоже права, кстати, но первые меняются  [cmod](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod), а вторые [chown](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не скажу, что у меня правильное решение, но напишу как я в итоге решил этот вопрос. Директорию /wp-content/cache/tmp плагин  не создавал, т.к. был не тот  владелец. Я вручную создал директорию /wp-content/cache, дал права 777, чтоб при установке плагина создалась нужная директория /wp-content/cache/tmp. После я дал права 755, как и положено.

Comment: Ну, значит, мой комментарий правильный. Проблема в том, что владелец был не тот.

Comment: И если бы сменили владельца сразу, то не пришлось бы танцев с 777 устраивать

Comment: +150! Нужно что б php исполнялся с правами, позволявшие ему писать в каталоги и создавать файлы (с правами юзера, а не вебсервера в общем). Иначе - это вечный геморрой и проблемы на ровном месте. Да и с безопасностью тоже оппа